# How do I read a species description that uses both ≡ (triple bar) and "incl." to denote synonymy?

Tags: botany, taxonomy

I'm trying to understand the relationship of plants formerly classified as *Dorstenia crispa* with distinct individuals continuously classified as *Dorstenia foetida*. I would assume that the distinctive phenotype would warrant a *var.* or *forma*, if not a subspecies, but I haven't seen it written as such anywhere.

I turned to monographs, which in [one case](https://books.google.com/books?id=ffBRAyZLuh0C&pg=PA319&lpg=PA319&dq=dorstenia%20foetida%20var.%20crispa&source=bl&ots=FouFcfLEsH&sig=DxuvJJv-2SmYL-lTJltQGojbils&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEIQ6AEwCmoVChMIjOLGr4vhyAIVRh0eCh161Q16#v=onepage&q=dorstenia%20foetida%20var.%20crispa&f=false) stated:

> **incl.** *Dorstenia crispa* Engler (1898); ... **incl.** *Dorstenia crispa* var. *lancifolia* Rendle (1915) ≡ *Dorstenia foetida* ssp. *lancifolia* (Rendle) Friis (1983);

1. Would this indicate that a specimen identified as *D. crispa* is properly identified **no more specifically** than as *D. foetida*?
2. Does this indicate that a specimen of *D. crispa v. lancifolia* is properly *D. foetida* ssp. *lancifolia*; or simply recognising that *D. crispa* v. *lancifolia* **and** *D. foetida* ssp. *lancifolia* would refer to the same individuals, which are properly still called nothing more than *D. foetida*?
3. Since these formerly-recognised infraspecific taxa do exist as separately-kept lines in cultivation, would they be properly recognised as cultivars?

My answer may simply be the closing remark in the above-quoted description, "Since the various forms are connected by intermediates, it is impossible to recognize infraspecific taxa." However, that's deeply-unsatisfying if cataloguing a collection that contains several now-synonymous specimens.

Comment: Welcome to Biology Stack Exchange! I think this is a fine question, and I look forward to hearing (or rather seeing) the answers!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the welcome, and hope this gets some answers myself. :-D

Comment: This seems like the type of thing that might vary from publication to publication. If you have access to the full book, maybe there's a key/glossary where you can find what the authors mean by these symbols

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the *Taxon* guidelines for authors](http://www.iapt-taxon.org/downloads/guidelines_authors.pdf) (pdf, pg 205), a triple-bar (≡) indicates a [homotypic synonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym_%28taxonomy%29#Botany):

> Homotypic names are cited in chronological order in a single paragraph with 
>   the identity sign (≡), followed by the type.

So, in your example, *Dorstenia foetida* was described on the basis of the same type specimen used by Forsskål in 1775 to describe *Kosaria foetida* -- or possibly a [neotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_%28biology%29#Neotype) was designated linking these two names, possibly by Schweinfurth in Bull. Herb. Boissier 4(App. 2): 120 in 1896. More information about the relevant type specimens would help sort this out.

Comment: That makes sense. How does it play with "incl.", then? I see, then, that _D. crispa_ var. _lancifolia_ shares a type with the superceding name _D. foetida_ ssp. _lancifolia_. What relationship does _that_ type have to _D. foetida_, indicated by the **incl.**? Is it simply that the taxonomist preparing this monograph is indicating his belief that they all _should_ share a type, even though currently they don't?

Comment: I'm afraid I have  no idea! If I had to guess, I'd guess that "A: incl. B" means that all individuals associated with the name B are considered by the taxonomist to belong to their circumscription of name A, without the requirement that they share a homonym. In some cases, it looks like B is a subspecies or variety, suggesting that these should be subsumed into A and not considered a separate entity. I'd hoped someone more knowledgeable would chime in but since that hasn't happened yet, here's my somewhat-informed guess!